# Creating a local ETH2 environment for testing L2 solutions

Tags: go-ethereum, testnets, protocol

I'm developing a Layer 2 network that runs on top of current Ethereum and has to do a lot with staking.

- run controlled local testnet incl beacon and staking.
- deploy smart contracts

What is the correct tool to spin up networks like this for testing my network?
I want the network to be similar to ethereum, to be able to move funds freely, stake them, and communicate with one of the nodes as a gateway.